# Java OOP - Physics Engine type

Tags: java, class, oop, interface

I am trying to create a n-body simulator in Java while also learning OOP.

I want to have a file that contains all physical constants and physics formulas and I want to use these in other classes when calculating forces etc

Should this file be a regular class with all variables static, an interface or an abstract class, or something else? I am quite confused with all the definitions.

Comment: Short answer: create a class named "Constants" and put those variables there as constants: "static public final float GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.81; // meters/second"

Comment: @JayC667 So all methods and constants in that class should be static?

Comment: Just make them all static members in a big "Globals" class. Some people frown on such things, but I frown on such people.

Comment: Methods and constants can be static if they don't depend on the state of an *instance* of that class.  You may have a class *BilliardBall* with member variable `Velocity`.  This changes for each BilliardBall, and can't be static.  But it may also have a static member variable `Mass`, since that doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I would create a class named `Physics` or something of that nature. Inside this class you can then accomplish all of the things you want to do by creating static methods and static variables, as JayC667 has pointed out. It should look something like this:

```
public class Physics {

    public static final int GRAVITY_ACCELERATION = 9.58;

    public static double formula(double x, double y) { ... }

    // etc.

}
```

Then, to utilize this class from a different one, you simply reference the variables and use the methods like so:

```
System.out.println("Acceleration of Gravity = " + Physics.GRAVITY_ACCELERATION);

double speed = Physics.formula(23.5, 840);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use **interfaces** to force classes (implementing those interfaces) to have defined methods (defined in the interface) you can can ensure basic functionality, while all the classes can be totally different in all other regards.

In an interface, you only define the method signature (return value, name, parameter types). These are purely abstract.

Since Java 8, interfaces can also contain *default* methods, that *may* contain code, but can be overridden by the implementing classes.

Best example is the Comparable interface. You can use that for Numbers, Strings, and any other classes that should be comparable (usually to their own class instances aka objects).

**Abstract classes** are a mixture of regular classes and interfaces. They contain code and member variables, but can also contain abstract methods. When a class *extends* an abstract base class, they need to implement the abstract methods at some point.

The **normal classes** do not have any abstract methods.

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer. So if I'm not mistaken, an interface would be beneficial in my case (or rather if I were to scale the application up)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question Java-developers usually fight over. General rules of thumb are the following:

- If you use a static field, always make it final and never try to mutate it.
- If you need a mutable field, create a non-static field.
- If possible, initialise the field in the constructor and mark it final.
- Methods are static only if they access no non-static fields (ie. they do not have a context), there is no need to abstract over them
  (for example in a test case) and they are completely functional (this should
  be implied by the fact that no static field is mutable). A good example is Math.sqrt(), where the square root operation does not have a context, does not mutate the state of your application and you never want to abstract over it. In all other cases use a non-static method. Some people completely avoid static methods.

Interfaces are most useful when your classes interact with one another. You can specify certain common functionalities available in a group of classes in your application. Then if some of your code requires these functionalities, you can use them without knowing the actual implementation. Say, you handle shapes in a method and want to know the area of a shape. You may have many shapes and you can retrieve the area without knowing the exact type (circle, triangle etc.).

In general, try not to overuse inheritance. Follow the substitution principle: only use inheritance if the superclass could always be substituted by the subclass.

For example: in OOP a square with variable slides is not a rectangle with variable slides, because for rectangles you are allowed to call `setSide(20, 30)`, while for squares you are not (the two sides must match). Note: if you use final fields which are initialized in the constructor, as suggested earlier, this problem is automatically solved and you are free to inherit square from rectangle.

In your case, I would create utility classes with static methods/fields for common functionalities that do not have a context, such as calculating a formula with given input parameters. The actual bodies could be objects with common interface or abstract parent class.

Answer (score 0):

This is some simple example of how you could do it.
Please ignore the aerial resistance part, didn't really think about that, some movements may be funny :-)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;



/**
 * Contains constants and convenience methods
 * @author JayC667
 */
class Globals {
    static public final float   GRAVITY_ACC = -9.81f;   // meters per second²

    static public float getTotalSpeed(final float pSpeedX, final float pSpeedY) {
        return (float) Math.sqrt(Math.pow(pSpeedX, 2) + Math.pow(pSpeedY, 2));
    }

    static public float getDistanceBetweenObjects(final PhysicalObjectInterface pObj1, final PhysicalObjectInterface pObj2) {
        final float distX = pObj2.getPosX() - pObj1.getPosX();
        final float distY = pObj2.getPosY() - pObj1.getPosY();
        return getTotalSpeed(distX, distY); // coincidentally same as average speed :-)
    }

    static public String toString(final PhysicalObjectInterface pObject) {
        return pObject.getClass().getSimpleName() + "\tX=" + pObject.getPosX() + "\tY=" + pObject.getPosY();
    }
}



interface PhysicalObjectInterface {
    default boolean collidesWith(final PhysicalObjectInterface pOther) {
        final float distance = Globals.getDistanceBetweenObjects(this, pOther);
        return distance < getRadius() + pOther.getRadius();
    }

    float getPosX();
    float getPosY();
    float getSpeedX();
    float getSpeedY();
    float getMass();
    float getRadius();
    float getAerialResistanceCofactor();
    void calcNextCycle();
}



/**
 * Does most of the simple work
 * @author JayC667
 */
abstract class PhysicalObjectABC implements PhysicalObjectInterface {

    private float   mPosX;
    private float   mPosY;
    private float   mSpeedX;
    private float   mSpeedY;

    public PhysicalObjectABC(final float pPosX, final float pPosY, final float pSpeedX, final float pSpeedY) {
        mPosX = pPosX;
        mPosY = pPosY;
        mSpeedX = pSpeedX;
        mSpeedY = pSpeedY;
    }

    @Override public float getPosX() {
        return mPosX;
    }
    @Override public float getPosY() {
        return mPosY;
    }
    @Override public float getSpeedX() {
        return mSpeedX;
    }
    @Override public float getSpeedY() {
        return mSpeedY;
    }

    @Override public abstract float getMass();
    @Override public abstract float getAerialResistanceCofactor(); // could also derive this from radius
    // getRadius is not repeated here, but still is abstract and has to be defined in the implementing subclass

    @Override public void calcNextCycle() {
        final float gravForceY = getMass() * Globals.GRAVITY_ACC; // F = m * a

        final float aerialResistForceX = -Math.signum(mSpeedX) * (float) (Math.pow(mSpeedX, 2) * getAerialResistanceCofactor());
        final float aerialResistForceY = -Math.signum(mSpeedY) * (float) (Math.pow(mSpeedY, 2) * getAerialResistanceCofactor());

        final float totalForceX = aerialResistForceX;
        final float totalForceY = gravForceY + aerialResistForceY;

        final float accX = totalForceX / getMass(); // a= F / m;
        final float accY = totalForceY / getMass(); // a= F / m;

        mSpeedX += accX;
        mSpeedY += accY;

        mPosX += mSpeedX;
        mPosY += mSpeedY;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return Globals.toString(this);
    }
}



class Stone extends PhysicalObjectABC {
    public Stone(final float pPosX, final float pPosY) {
        super(pPosX, pPosY, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override public float getRadius() {
        return 0.1f;
    }
    @Override public float getMass() {
        return 1;
    }
    @Override public float getAerialResistanceCofactor() {
        return 0.2f;
    }
}



class Leaf extends PhysicalObjectABC {
    public Leaf(final float pPosX, final float pPosY) {
        super(pPosX, pPosY, 0, 0);
    }

    @Override public float getRadius() {
        return 0.1f;
    }
    @Override public float getMass() {
        return 0.003f;
    }
    @Override public float getAerialResistanceCofactor() {
        return 0.95f;
    }
}



class StaticObject implements PhysicalObjectInterface {

    private final int   mPosX;
    private final int   mPosY;
    private final int   mRadius;

    public StaticObject(final int pPosX, final int pPosY, final int pRadius) {
        mPosX = pPosX;
        mPosY = pPosY;
        mRadius = pRadius;
    }

    @Override public float getPosX() {
        return mPosX;
    }
    @Override public float getPosY() {
        return mPosY;
    }
    @Override public float getSpeedX() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override public float getSpeedY() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override public float getMass() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override public float getRadius() {
        return mRadius;
    }
    @Override public float getAerialResistanceCofactor() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override public void calcNextCycle() { /* ignore, does not move */}

    @Override public String toString() {
        return Globals.toString(this);
    }
}



public class PhysicsEngine {

    static private ArrayList<PhysicalObjectInterface>   sObjects    = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        sObjects.add(new Leaf(10, 100));
        sObjects.add(new Stone(20, 100));
        sObjects.add(new Leaf(30, 100));
        sObjects.add(new Stone(40, 100));
        sObjects.add(new StaticObject(30, 100, 1)); // lantern
        sObjects.add(new StaticObject(40, 100, 5)); // tree

        for (int cycle = 0; cycle < 1000; cycle++) {
            simulateCycle(cycle);
            printData(cycle);
            checkCollisions(cycle);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (final InterruptedException e) { /* ignore */}
        }
    }

    private static void simulateCycle(final int pCycle) {
        System.out.println("Simulating cycle #" + pCycle);
        for (final PhysicalObjectInterface o : sObjects) {
            o.calcNextCycle();
        }
    }

    private static void printData(final int pCycle) {
        System.out.println("Printing cycle #" + pCycle);
        for (final PhysicalObjectInterface o : sObjects) {
            System.out.println("\t" + o);
        }
    }

    private static void checkCollisions(final int pCycle) {
        System.out.println("Checking for collisions in cycle #" + pCycle);
        final ArrayList<PhysicalObjectInterface> destroyedItems = new ArrayList<>();

        for (final PhysicalObjectInterface o1 : sObjects) {
            for (final PhysicalObjectInterface o2 : sObjects) {
                if (o1 == o2) continue; // ignore IDENTICAL, not equal, items
                if (o1.collidesWith(o2)) {
                    System.out.println("CRASH!\n\tObject 1 (" + o1 + ") \ncollides with \n\tObject 2 (" + o2 + ")");
                    destroyedItems.add(o1);
                    destroyedItems.add(o2);
                }
            }
        }

        sObjects.removeAll(destroyedItems); // can't delete within loop, would invalidate iterators or migh also f*** up loop indices
    }
}
```